# how to open a web browser inside azure function app running on linux with python code

Tags: python, linux, selenium, webdriver, azure-functions

i have created an azure function app with a python code. my code is going to **scrape** tripadvisor page so i used Selenium to open browser and get the source code for a tripadvisor page. Locally on my machine every thing work fine but on azure the function app that i created can't open the web browser.
the error that i get is 'geckodriver' executable may have wrong permissions.

I tried changing permission like this

but the same probleme happen again

```
AppInsightsScraper.my_logger.info('opening browser')
cmd = 'sudo chmod 777 "/home/site/wwwroot/geckodriver"'
AppInsightsScraper.my_logger.info(os.system(cmd))
checkCmd = 'ls -l'
AppInsightsScraper.my_logger.info(os.system(checkCmd))
AppInsightsScraper.my_logger.info('test modif permission')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/site/wwwroot/geckodriver')
AppInsightsScraper.my_logger.info('browser opened')
```

the expected result is to open the browser and continue the execution of my code but i get permission error on azure portal  'geckodriver' executable may have wrong permissions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LZaY.png)
i can't even understand what 32512 and 0 means in the log informations

Answer (score 0):

The error possibly means that geckodriver isn't on the path so it can't do what you want it to do. I received a similar error for Chromedriver on one of my Django app services on Azure and after hours of searching for solutions online, I'm afraid I have bad news for you.

1. Azure won't allow you to install custom software which is required for your app to run (firefox for geckodriver, chrome for chromedriver etc)
2. Even if somehow magically there's firefox available, you will have to specify environment variables for your geckodriver and firefox, which is another hectic task on azure.

But there's an alternative if you are okay to deploy somewhere else instead of Azure (Heroku worked for me). You can easily add the firefox binary and geckodriver buildpack and set the path variables and it'll run like a charm. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ven-pqwk3ec) tutorial for the same, I hope it helps.